# How do I hide StartApp ad on my app?

Tags: android, ads, startapp

I want to hide/stop the 3d banner ad when user makes an inapp purchase. But I can't figure out how to.

The ad starts automatically when the activity is launched and there is no way of stopping it

```
<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D
    android:id="@+id/startApp3DBanner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        startAppAd.onResume();
```

.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppAd.init(this, C.STARTAPP_DEV_ID, C.STARTAPP_APP_ID);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following line to hide the banner:

```
((Banner3D) findViewById(R.id.startApp3DBanner)).hideBanner();
```

And:

```
((Banner3D) findViewById(R.id.startApp3DBanner)).showBanner();
```

For showing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in their [support page](https://support.startapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/202766793-Hiding-an-In-App-Banner-Ad-).

You need to call this to hide the ad banner:

```
startAppBanner.hideBanner();
```

And you can put this in the `onCreate` method. Alternatively, you can have a boolean value that checks if the user has made an in-app purchase, and then hide the view through `banner.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.